# How to run a script I wrote like a command?

Tags: bash

I have a shell file, for example `wd.sh` and I want to turn this into a command called `wd` that I can run without having to sh it, just like running `cat`, `sort`, or any other UNIX command.

How do I do this?

Like

`wd file1 file2`

Answer (score 3):

I recommend this way (using a user local `~/bin` dir) :

```
cd
mkdir -p bin
cat<<EOF>bin/wd
#!/bin/bash

echo "it works"
EOF
chmod +x bin/wd
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
wd
```

(You just have to cppy/paste the whole code in the same time in a (pseudo)terminal)

To keep the PATH modified after opening another shell, use an editor to open `~/.bashrc` and add the

```
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

line.

Comment: Fixed typo in post

Comment: For security's sake, it's probably best to have your personal `~/bin` folder at the **end** of your path, rather than the beginning: `export PATH="$PATH:~/bin"`. This way if some piece of malware sneaks into it, it won't get run before an identically-named system command, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler solution: make an alias !

```
echo "alias wd='bash /somedir/somesubdir/myscript.sh'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
source ~/.bashrc
```

And you're done. You don't even need to make the script executable

Comment: Not everyone have `source ~/.bash_aliases` in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Shell functions are preferred over aliases.

Comment: @chepner: preferred by you ? by yourself ? Using a function is useless in this case.

Comment: From the `bash` man page:  "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions."

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the path of the current folder to the ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=$PATH:CURRENT_DIRECTORY_PATH
```